# The map is covering the toggle button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Do you by any chance know how to put the side bar toggle over the map? the map  always cover my toggle button. I'm using bootstrap simple sidebar. Thanks very much!!!
https://codepen.io/william251082/pen/rGNPqr

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">

        <ul class="sidebar-nav">          

     <p><h1>Locations</h1></p>
     <form>
     <input placeholder="Search..." type="search" data-bind="textInput: filter">
     </form>

    <ul data-bind="foreach: myLocations">
        <li data-bind="text: name, visible: visible, click: $root.listViewClick" ></li>
    </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->  

    <div id="page-content-wrapper">

      <div class="container-fluid"> 

        <div id="map"></div>
      <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-secondary" id="menu-toggle">&#9776;</a>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

<!-- /#wrapper -->
```

---

```
   #map {
width: 100%;
margin-left:10%;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;

}
#menu-toggle {
        width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    margin:10 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make position relative and move it. position absolute makes it get out of document flow. This is what leads to overlap. If Overlap is not desired avoid using `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0):

How about with z-index ?

```
#menu-toggle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: black;
    margin:10 10;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your padding on the left is on 10px however the toggle button is 50px. Try make the margin for the map 50px and lower the width down to 90%.

```
  ` #map {
       width: 90%;
       position: absolute;
       height: 100%;
     } 
    #menu-toggle {
       width: 50px;
       height: 40px;
       background-color: black;
      }`
```

Also removed some margins